# How to add some style only for main parrent in SASS

Tags: css, sass, parent

I have this markup:

```
<ul> // w style: border-top: 2px solid #aaa; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  <li>
    <ul> // w style: border-bottom: 2px solid #aaa;
      <li>
      <li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to add some style to the main parent and a touch of style that will be inherited for the same item within - as above. So i do this, but it is't work...

```
ul {
   border-top: 2px solid #aaa;

   & > {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
   }
}
```

I know that I can duplicate tag and specify a different style for him inside, but in general is the possibility of such record/write? Thx for help.

Comment: You can't do it without writing `ul` again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your use of the nested selector is wrong, it must be throwing errors from Sass.
You have used the direct descendent selector `>` after the alias for the containing selector in this case the `ul`, so your compiled selector would look like `ul >` which is invalid.

The selector should follow the pattern `parent > child`. You may be attempting `ul > ul` but the nested `ul` is not a direct descendent of the main `ul` rather it is a child of `li`.

Your amended code:

```
ul {
   border-top: 2px solid #aaa;

   & > li > & {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
   }
}
```

But note this rule will also apply in the following situation too, so you should probably go for a class on the nested `ul`.

**HTML**

```
<ul> // w style: border-top: 2px solid #aaa; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  <li>
    <ul> // w style: border-bottom: 2px solid #aaa;
      <li>
        <ul> // Another list
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      <li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So this would be better

```
<ul> // w style: border-top: 2px solid #aaa; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  <li>
    <ul class='sub-list'> // w style: border-bottom: 2px solid #aaa;
      <li>
      <li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

with the following css/scss

```
ul {
  border-top: 2px solid #aaa;
}

.sub-list { /* Will inherit the above if used on a ul */
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```